# How to apply reverse animation on Navigator.pop() using flutter_animate package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-routes

I'm applying a fade animation to my full-screen overlay widget using flutter_animate.

Animating "opening" the overlay is as simple as adding a single line of code like `Animate(effects: const [FadeEffect()], child: const AddOverlay()),)`

However, I cannot figure out how to reverse the fade effect when closing the overlay using  `Navigator.of(context).pop(context);`

Below is a minimum reproducible code, with a default boilerplate flutter project.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_animate/flutter_animate.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Animated Transition',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            PageRouteBuilder(
              opaque: false,
              pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) => Animate(
                  effects: const [FadeEffect()],
                  child:
                      const AddOverlay()), // Using flutter_animate package to add animation to opening the overlay widget
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddOverlay({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.85),
      body: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(
          sigmaX: 5.0,
          sigmaY: 5.0,
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(
                      context); // Closing the overlay should also have a fade animation effect.
                },
                child: const Text("Close"))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why we need to use `flutter_animate` for this case. You can achieve the desired effect by using the built-in `FadeTransition` widget combined with the `pageTransitionBuilder`, which allows you to customize the animation during the page `push` or `pop` transition. When pushing, the animation value will go from 0 to 1.0, and it will reverse when the route is popping.

The routing part where customise the transition :

```
  void _navigateToAddOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
          return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
        },
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => const AddOverlay(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

here is your full updated code: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zk3e0614k3f0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart